# Sad face grey box showing up in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am running Version 34.0.1847.131 of chrome and am having issues (well a co-worker is having issues with certain sites and I was able to reproduce them) with grey boxes showing up on some sites as if a certain site element couldn't be loaded.  I have not been able to get rid of them at this point, any suggestions?

The only add on I currently have is IE Tab.

Screenshots:

[image: box1]

[image]

Comment: That's the icon you get when the webpage is not available. [pic](https://community.republicwireless.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-127746-4133/chrome1.png). Looks like your workplace is blocking certain sites, and the contents of that box can't be accessed.

Comment: usually when things are blocked by work I get a white box with something along the lines of "This content is blocked by your organization" etc etc etc.  Same thing though?

Comment: Not too sure about it, actually. You should probably try accessing this site outside of work to see if the same thing happens.

Comment: Good point.  Ill give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

What I can tell from my experience is that flash player (or something like it) isn't working on these specific sites. Try updating flash player and see if anything happends.

**EDIT 1:**
I just remembered that chrome has disabled flash player. Try enabling it in the **NPAPI-settings**. (details here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033)

Answer (score 1):

End all of chrome processes via Task Manager (*simply closing it doesn't stop the services from running in the background*).

Once done so, re-opened up Chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full cause but there appears to be a session issue with SSO (more specifically spnego). I am getting the frowny face when I try to SSO to a 2nd server after successfully SSOing to a 1st server. Only closing the browser resolves. This issue is further complicated when a portal is at play (where SSO is needed to the portal and then a 2nd SSO is needed to links to another server. Problem is not reproducible in IE (everything works fine)